# Google AutoML training error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I loaded a dataset into google automl, using the UI. I got the message that I have enough labeled text and can start training, however when I click on Start Training, I get the error

Exception while handling your request: Request contains an invalid argument.
When reporting refer to this issue by its tracking code tc_698293

As I am using the UI, I don't know what the arguments of the request are. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: consider adding more information about your question

Answer (score 2):

It is required to have at least 2 examples in all of TRAIN, TEST and VALIDATION set to start training.

The error message could be more clear about that and the UI could check for that condition and warn users early. In short term better error message will be provided.