# "Invalid arguments of request" when clicking "Start training" i

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl

I have uploaded 22 images and tagged with 2 tags.

But when I click start training I get an "Invalid arguments of request".

The images have been uploaded through the interface. I had to manually create the bucket.

What can have gone wrong? I have attached a screenshot.

[image: google cloud automl]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely the same error as in [Google AutoML training error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573538/google-automl-training-error/51599412#51599412)

Each image is assigned for one of `TRAIN`, `VALIDATION`, and `TEST` set. You have enough labeled images, but not enough images assigned for `VALIDATION` or `TEST`. Adding images for these two sets should solve this issue.

The best way of adding images to specified sets is [importing a CSV file](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#csv).

Comment: How can I assign images to VALIDATION and TEST ?  I am using upload files from my computer option to try it instead of the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Preparing your training data](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare)

If you use csv file to import data, you need to assign the content to specific data set. (You need to upload your file to GCS first)

Ex.

```
TRAIN, gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_1}, {LABLE}
VALIDATION, gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_2}, {LABLE}
TEST, gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_3}, {LABLE}
```

or do not assign the data set, AutoML automatically places it in one of the three sets

```
gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_1}, {LABLE}
gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_2}, {LABLE}
gs://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/{OBJECT_NAME_3}, {LABLE}
```